# Implementing a password field using C

Tags: c

Is is possible to implement the password field which we see on webpages using C language???

Comment: What operating system and/or GUI framework are you targeting? Most of them have support for such a thing built-in.

Comment: Yes. Do you want to make or modify a web server, a web client, or a graphical user interface?

Comment: I am on Windows and using TurboC3. Is there any built-in support there in some header file??? If yes, please let me know.

Comment: Erm, Turbo C came out a little over 100 years ago. It's time to upgrade compilers. It doesn't even compile Windows applications, much less modern C code. Who knows what header files came with it. In Windows, you want to create an Edit control with the `ES_PASSWORD` style flag.

Comment: Well, I just stumbled upon this question somewhere. So was trying it out just for fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can serve the purpose:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX 25
#define passfield 1

void main()
{
 char password[MAX], passchar;
 int i=0;
 clrscr();
 printf("Enter password: ");
 while(passfield)
 {
  passchar=getch();
  if(passchar==13)
   break; // 13 is the ASCII value of ENTER
  if(passchar==8) // 8 is the ASCII value of BACKSPACE
  {
   putch('\b');
   putch(NULL);
   putch('\b');
   --i;
   continue;
  }
  password[i++]=passchar; //else store characters in password
  passchar='*'; //mask password character
  putch(passchar);
 }
 password[i]='\0'; //end of the char array
 printf("\n%s",password);
 getch();
}
```

Comment: -1: Never use this code in production, anywhere, ever. It does not do what you think it does, and while it also fails that, it's also vulnerable to a blatant buffer overflow attack. It's hard to imagine how people can write crap like this and it gets accepted.

Comment: The problem is that the next idiot who comes along looking for "C" and "password fields" may just take this and drop it into an application in production somewhere. "Here, just use this live grenade as a door jam. It works!"

Comment: @Joshua: Agreed, it's like something you'd see in C For Dummies. But its accepted because the asker is using Turbo C, and this is about the only code that it will compile...

Comment: @JoshuaK - It seems that you were day dreaming somewhere and suddenly came here to pour your heart out...I can understand the feelings...But before commenting in future make sure you go through all the comments which have been made earlier and try to figure out what the asker intends to ask...Sometimes it does happen that silly questions have silly answers...

Comment: Not sure where the daydreaming happened. Code like this should never be used. Joshua has a point that lots of people see code in a SO answer, assume it's good code, and use it. You have to be very careful with power like that.

Comment: @CodyGray: Right...I'll be careful next time.